# select não está exibindo dados da chamada API no Vue

Tags: vue.js

Tenho um select que deve exibir uma lista de objetos retornada por uma chamada de API, entretanto o Vue não está renderizando a lista. Os objetos estão sendo armazenados na variável, porém não estão sendo exibidos.
Abaixo o código:

**HTML**

```
<select id="tipo_empresa" v-model="empresa.tipo_empresa">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Tipo de empresa</option>
    <option v-for="tipo in this.tipos" v-bind:key="tipo.id_em_tipo" v-bind:value="tipo.id_em_tipo">{{ tipo.descricao}}</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    const axios = require('axios');
    export default {
        data(){
           return {
               tipos: [],
               empresa: {
                   tipo_empresa: ''
               }
           }
        },
        mounted(){
             $(document).ready(function() {
                 $('#tipo_empresa').formSelect();
             });
             this.getTipos();
        },
        methods() {
            popularSelect (){
                axios.get(URL, header)
                .then(res => (this.tipos = res.data));
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

**Obs.:** No meu código estão as variáveis da chamada de api (URL e header). Na extensão VueDevTools para o Chrome a variável "tipos" aparece populada, com os objetos. Se eu imprimo a variável na tela ela também exibe os objetos, porém no select não está funcionando.

**Obs2.:** No navegador Edge ele está funcionando, porém em todos os outros, não.

Comment: você está usando JQuery e Vuejs na mesma aplication ? O loco

Comment: Na realidade é só para inicializar o select do Materialize, mas eu sei que não é recomendado. Além disso, o materialize não tem mais a obrigatoriedade de usar o jquery e eu já tentei usando o javascript puro e esse não é o problema.

Comment: Não precisas do `this` aqui: `this.tipos`. Usa somente `v-for="tipo in tipos"`

Comment: Que tristeza Jquery e Vue :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com a ajuda de um colega, nós descobrimos uma solução. A inicialização do componente select estava no ciclo mounted() do Vue. Alteramos para o ciclo updated().

Creio que preciso estudar melhor o ciclo de vida do Vue.

A seguir, vou deixar como ficou o código **JS** para futuras referências:

```
<script>
const axios = require('axios');
export default {
    data(){
       return {
           tipos: [],
           empresa: {
               tipo_empresa: ''
           }
       }
    },
    updated(){
         document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
             var elems = document.querySelectorAll('#tipo_empresa');
             var options = {};
             var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems, options);
         });
         this.getTipos();
    },
    methods() {
        popularSelect (){
            axios.get(URL, header)
            .then(res => (this.tipos = res.data));
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

**EDIT**

Conforme o comentário do @sergio, eu, também, retirei o `this` da variável do `v-for` ficando assim:

**HTML**

```
<select id="tipo_empresa" v-model="empresa.tipo_empresa">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Tipo de empresa</option>
    <option v-for="tipo in tipos" v-bind:key="tipo.id_em_tipo" v-bind:value="tipo.id_em_tipo">{{ tipo.descricao}}</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT 2**

Removi o Jquery do projeto, agora a inicialização do componente está com javascript puro.

Comment: Como é que ficou o `v-for` no template?

Comment: Do modo como você havia comentado, sem o "this". `code`<select>